# Displaying Facebook Like Button Count

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-like, pinterest

Facebook Like button displays by default without the like count, how do you load it with by default to display count, even when 0?

```
 <fb:like href="url" send="false" layout="button_count" width="100px" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
```

And also how about Pinterest? It's a similar concept.

Comment: @Yan Yea sure, here you go: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: @ZeeTee Your question sounds like something that should go into Facebook Support. Here, we can't do anything better if it ain't in Facebook's docs. Also, when you want to customize the Facebook button, every knows you should do it from scratch.

Comment: @ZeeTee Your question has been downvoted because it doesn't show any effort of research. The answer lies within a simple Google Search: _facebook like button_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iframe version contains the display count even when its a zero.

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOUR_URL&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21&amp;appId=401883116500986" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```